# Easily access properties of a static class python

Tags: python, properties, static

I have a static class defined below that has two example of some default properties that I will be referencing in my code. This class will be much larger later on but I wanted a good way to keep all these values in one place, and access them in several areas of code.

'''

```
class Defaults:

    Refractive: Tuple[float, float, float] = (0.5, 1.333, 5.0)
    Temp: Tuple[int, int, int] = (10, 23, 40)

    @staticmethod
    def Min(property: Tuple[Any, Any, Any]) -> Any:
        return property[0]
    @staticmethod
    def Max(property: Tuple[Any, Any, Any]) -> Any:
        return property[2]
    @staticmethod
    def Default(property: Tuple[Any, Any, Any]) -> Any:
        return property[1]
```

'''

Is there a way to access specific indices of these properties such as:

```
Defaults.Temp.Min()
```

Instead of this:

```
Defaults.Min(Defaults.Temp)
```

Or is there a better data structure to use here? Thanks.

Comment: What's a "static class"?  This probably shouldn't be a class.

Comment: Did you mean `Defaults.Temp`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a class for this, and making this a method really doesn't make sense. Use *another object* instead of a static method:

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", int, float)

# it doesn't have to be a namedtuple, either, you could just define a regular class
class MetaData(NamedTuple, Generic[T]): # or a better name
    min: T
    default: T
    max: T

class Defaults:
    Refractive: MetaData[float] = MetaData(0.5, 1.333, 5.0)
    Temp: MetaData[int] = MetaData(10, 23, 40)
```

Then, you can just do:

```
print(Defaults.Temp.min)
```

Note, you should **avoid `Any`**, it pretty much defeats the purpose of typing! It basically mean, "don't type check this". It serves as an "escape valve".

Note, Python isn't Java/C#... there really is no need for a "static class", indeed, taht isn't standard terminology. Normally, this would just be a *regular module* with global level "constants", e.g.

```
# in defaults.py
Refractive: MetaData[float] = MetaData(0.5, 1.333, 5.0)
Temp: MetaData[int] = MetaData(10, 23, 40)
```

Comment: This answer seems to accomplish what I'm looking to do. 
Im getting an mypy error however stating: Argument 1 to "MetaData" has incompatible type "float; expected "T"
Ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: Disregard my question, see my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified @juanpa.arrivullaga's answer to the following below which works how I wanted. Wasn't sure about the error I was getting from their answer detailed in my comment on their answer, but the below solution works for me. Thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga :)

```
class IntData(NamedTuple):
    """Tuple(Minimum, Default, Maximum) Int"""
    Min: int
    Default: int
    Max: int


class FloatData(NamedTuple):
    """Tuple(Minimum, Default, Maximum) Float"""
    Min: float
    Default: float
    Max: float


class ProtocolDefaults:
    RI: FloatData = FloatData(0.5, 1.333, 5.0)
    Temperature: IntData = IntData(10, 23, 40)


class SettingDefaults:
    CT: FloatData = FloatData(20, 25, 30)
```

Access elements via:

```
ProtocolDefaults.Temperature.Min
```